# glRotatef results on a wirecube

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using a rand() function for and x variable and y variable to be used in glRotatef. Rand is working just fine. What is happening is when I get a 0 value in both X and Y, the cube fluctuates by shrinking and inflating. I have tried a couple of ways to make sure this does not happen but alas, I am here. Here is the function I am working with:

```
void initRandoms()
{
    maxCubes = rand() % (CUBE_HIGH - CUBE_LOW + 1) + CUBE_LOW;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxCubes; i++)
    {
        cubeOrigins[i].x = X_LOW + (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX * (X_HIGH - X_LOW);
        cubeOrigins[i].y = Y_LOW + (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX * (Y_HIGH - Y_LOW);
        //cubeOrigins[i].z = 
        cubeOrigins[i].size = SIZE_LOW + (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX * (SIZE_HIGH - SIZE_LOW);
        cubeOrigins[i].rotateX = rand() % 2;
        cubeOrigins[i].rotateY = rand() % 2;


    }
```

As I said before, each cube will rotate either on the X-axis, Y-axis, XY-axis or shrink and inflate. It is the shrink and inflate I need to remove which corresponds to 0 = X AND 0 = Y. I can have X = 0 OR Y = 0. What I have tried is some if else conditionals but what happens is I take the shrink & inflate out but then all the cubes rotate in the same direction. I am hoping someone can figure out what I am doing wrong and show me what I need to do. I appreciate everyone's help. I will put more code up if needed.

Here is myDisplay function where the above function is used. The above function is also called in main:

```
void myDisplay()
{

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
for(int i = 0; i < maxCubes; i++)
{

    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -120.0);
    glTranslatef(cubeOrigins[i].x, cubeOrigins[i].y, cubeZ);
    glRotatef(rotateAxis, cubeOrigins[i].rotateX, cubeOrigins[i].rotateY, 0.0f);
    //glRotatef(rotateAxis, 1, 1, 0);

    glutWireCube(cubeOrigins[i].size);
}

cubeZ += 0.050f;
glutSwapBuffers();
glFlush();

if (cubeZ > 120.0f)
{
    cubeZ -= 100.f;
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    for(int i = 0; i < maxCubes; i++)
    {
        initRandoms();
        glLoadIdentity();

        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -120.0);
        glTranslatef(cubeOrigins[i].x, cubeOrigins[i].y, cubeZ);
        glRotatef(rotateAxis, cubeOrigins[i].rotateX, cubeOrigins[i].rotateY, 0.0f);
        //glRotatef(rotateAxis, 1, 1, 0);

        glutWireCube(cubeOrigins[i].size);

    }
    cubeZ += 0.050f;
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}
}
```

Comment: Prefer the `<random>` header.

Comment: Well, first of all, using modulo arithmetic on `rand (...)` has a negative impact on the distribution of results. What you should do is divide by `RAND_MAX` (use floating-point division) and then multiply by your desired range. This is all explained clearly at [c-faq.com](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)

Comment: @chris Not sure what you mean but the <random> header has NOTHING to do with the stated question, being as I have the <random> header at the top of my code.

Comment: @Clint, Partly what was said above, but the other part is that `rand` pales in comparison to, say, a `std::mt19937`, and the modulo is less explicit and does a worse job than a `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

Comment: I do not believe anyone is actually reading the question or maybe I phrased it incorrectly, but folks this has nothing to do with the results of rand. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Nobody said that it did, but you are doing something that is seriously frowned upon among those in the know. It deserves at least some mention; these are comments after all, not answers.

Comment: BTW: glRotatef is an old-style way of doing stuff in OpenGL. I thought I should post this comment since many people seem to be unaware of modern OpenGL.

Comment: @luiscubal, I am sure you are correct, but where we are in our text is where we are.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman point is taken and will "rewrite" the rand function close to the three rand functions above it.

Comment: Okay, now that we have that out of the way I am beginning to suspect the problem is related to the order you rotate and scale in. Additionally, I am not sure whether you are accumulating these transformations for each cube or applying them correctly per-instance. The much more important piece of code to show in your question would be where you apply your matrix transformations (`glRotatef (...)`, `glScalef (...)`, `glPushMatrix (...)`, etc.)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman question has been updated with more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, I could see that you are rotating your cubes by using this function:

```
glRotatef(rotateAxis, cubeOrigins[i].rotateX, cubeOrigins[i].rotateY, 0.0f);
```

The question is: What happens when both, cubeOrigins[i].rotateX and cubeOrigins[i].rotateY are zero? OpenGL rotates matrix by using a mathematic function called quaternion (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRotate.xml) and, when x, y and z are zero, I guess (because your are violating one of its premises that is ||x, y, z|| must be 1) it is reduced to this matrix:

```
|cos(angle)   0       0      0|
|   0   cos(angle)    0      0|
|   0         0   cos(angle) 0|
|   0         0       0      1|
```

which is essentially a scale matrix. This explain your beforementioned effect of shrinking and inflating.

So, as you observed before, you need to avoid this situation.

Second, you are using, for all cubes, the same `rotateAxis`. So, every cube that is with same cubeOrigins[i].rotateX and cubeOrigins[i].rotateY will got the same rotations. You need to get some variations here (changing rotateAxis for each cube)

Finally, you dont need to call both:

```
glutSwapBuffers();
glFlush();
```

glutSwapBuffers() already call, internally glFlush

Comment: I suppose the question is how do I avoid that? I have tried a few things as mentioned above and that is my problem.

Comment: I suposed, it was clear. Use, instead of rotateAxis, rand()%180 and an if condition ( if x == 0 && y == 0 ) x = 1 )

Comment: One of the things I did try is what you suggested and to no avail, this does not work: `if (cubeOrigins[i].rotateX == 0 && cubeOrigins[i].rotateY == 0)
  {
   cubeOrigins[i].rotateX == 1;
  }` Inside the for loop of the initRandoms() function.

Comment: @Clint Not `cubeOrigins[i].rotateX == 1;` but `cubeOrigins[i].rotateX = 1;`. Just one equal

Comment: Dang! I should have known that. Thank you very much. Why rotate 180 as opposed to 360 which is what I have?

Comment: You Sir have been checked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

first things first pls

(im not sure if you already did but)

before using the C ***rand()*** method you need to give it a seed so that you get "real" random numbers using the ***srand()*** function

Comment: It has be perfectly seeded. Guys, this is a function I am getting the desired results of rand. Now I wish I had never mentioned rand.

Comment: well then: rand() % 2 will return only 0 or 1 and nothing else meaning you should do something like (float)1 / rand() instead

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).